# Why is $x\times(z+y)$ equal to $zx+xy$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My question is why multiplying side quantities to an expression containing brackets remove the bracket, like below?
$$x\times(z+y) =zx+xy$$

Comment: It's because of the usual operator precedence, where multiplication has higher precedence. You don't have to remove the parentheses, for example you could write $x \cdot (z + y) = (x \cdot z) + (x \cdot y)$, but the parentheses are redundant on the right hand side. On the left hand side, however, they are not redundant: you can not write $x \cdot z + y$ instead, because that would compute the multiplication first so it is not the same thing.

Comment: @CristianGratie OP asked about x(z+y)=zx+xy which is not what you addressed.

Comment: @coffeemath The question was about the parentheses, so I answered that. I personally assumed it's a typo, but in any case $xz = xz$ by commutativity so I don't see the issue.

Comment: @CristianGratie You mean $xz=zx$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, of course. And so I realize that one cannot edit their comment...

Comment: @CristianGratie You can edit your comment if you do it within 5 minutes of posting.

Answer (score 1):

The equation $$x\cdot(y+z)=x\cdot{y}+x\cdot{z}$$ is known as the axiom of distributivity. Why is it true? Roughly speaking... because we say so. That is it. Algebraic structures in mathematics can obey an axiom, or not obey it. The ones we happen to like are the ones that do obey it. So those are the ones we learn about in education. It is an extremely important axiom, because it allows us to compute products by using what we know about addition.

Now, it sounds like your confusion lies mainly with the notation. Multiplying $x$ by the sum of $y+z$ does not simply "remove the parentheses." That is not really how that works. Parentheses are not actually part of the mathematics being carried out, they are just a notational tool to avoid ambiguity in interpreting the symbols being used. Technically, the axiom of distributivity should be written as $$x\cdot(y+z)=(x\cdot{y})+(x\cdot{z}),$$  but the parentheses on the right-hand side do not need to be written, because by convention, multiplication is taken to have higher priority than addition. So what the axiom is really saying has nothing to do with parentheses, and everything to do with what comes first. The product of a quantity and a sum is equal to the sum of the product of that quantity and the individual summands. That is all the axiom is saying.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplication (of natural numbers, at least) is simply repeated addition: $5 \times 3$ essentially equals adding 3 five times ($3+3$$+3+3+3$) or conversely, adding 5 three times. Likewise, $x \times (z+y)$ involves adding the $(z+y)$ term **$\mathbf{x}$ times**.

$$(z + y) + (z+y) + ... +(z+y) $$
$$= z + y + z + y + ... + z + y$$

Note that the brackets don't mean much here and can hence be simply removed. Since $z$ and $y$ were added $x$ times, we can write...

$$xz + xy$$

...which is equal to the original statement. This is the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property).

---

Also, just for kicks, here's an animation I have made showing the distributive property geometrically. You can see that the area of the larger rectangle equals the sum of the area of the smaller rectangles that make it up ($xy+xz$) which is equivalent to multiplying its length times the breadth $x \cdot (y+z)$.

[image]

Comment: This is inaccurate. Multiplication is not repeated addition. You cannot add a $-\frac12$ term $-\frac12$ times to evaluate $(-\frac12)(-\frac12).$ That is literally nonsensical. Yet multiplication of fractions, real numbers, complex numbers, and even non-numerical structures, such as matrices, is well-defined, and in all those cases, the distributitve property is still satisfied. In fact, you have it backwards. Multiplication is *defined* by the distributive property, and this property simplifies to repeated addition in the special case of natural numbers, because of how natural numbers are..

Comment: ...defined. So this is not an adequate explanation.

Comment: @Angel That is true, but I think regarding multiplication as being repeated addition (for natural numbers) is sufficient for the OP to develop an intuition for why the property works.

Comment: @Angel I mean... you *can* add $-\frac12$ of $-frac12$, it just ends up becoming the multiplication itself, since you only add the $\frac14$ once. It does look silly, of course. However, repeated addition is understood intuitively and works for the integers (not just $\mathbb{N}$ and the Gaussian integers. But by the time a student is dealing rational numbers, they likely already understand multiplication separately from addition.

Comment: @EricSnyder That is inaccurate, Repeated multiplication works if you are working with the natural numbers. But you cannot coherently define a product of two negative integers as a repeated sum of only negative integers. At some point, you eventually have to say $(-1)(-1)=1,$ which can only be established using the distributive property, and not via repeated addition. With the Gaussian integers, a similar concept applies. And with the rational numbers, it definitely does not work, let alone higher structures, And that is precisely my point. Multiplication IS separate from addition.

Answer (score 0):

If you think of $xy$ as the area of a rectangle with base $x$ and height $y$ you can use Euclid's geometric proof of the distributive law:

> Book II, Proposition 1: If there are two straight lines, and one of them
> is cut into any number of segments whatever, then the rectangle
> contained by the two straight lines equals the sum of the rectangles
> contained by the uncut straight line and each of the segments.

[image]

[https://mathcs.clarku.edu/~djoyce/elements/bookII/propII1.html](https://mathcs.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookII/propII1.html)